# ShipIt node/express deployment with PM2 - cannot set the correct NODE_ENV

Tags: node.js, pm2, shipitjs

I am trying to start my node app in the correct environment upon deployment with ShipIt ( w ships-npm plugin) ? I am deploying it in the staging env, but the app starts in development mode as stated displaying yj-he process.env.NODE_ENV

deployment with ships

```
>$ shipit staging deploy
Starting deployment...
....
Running 'start_server' task...
Running "cd /opt/hello/releases/20161128182300 && npm start" on host "myhost.live".
@myhost.live 
@myhost.live > hello-world-express@0.0.1 start /opt/hello/releases/20161128182300
@myhost.live > pm2 startOrReload ecosystem.json
@myhost.live 
@myhost.live [PM2] Applying action reloadProcessId on app [hello](ids: 0)
@myhost.live [PM2] [hello](0) ✓
@myhost.live ┌──────────┬────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬──────────
@myhost.live │ App name │ id │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime
```

├──────────┼────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼──────────
    @myhost.live │ hello    │ 0  │ fork │ 7224 │ online │ 2       │ 0s
└──────────┴────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴──────────
    @myhost16.live  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
    Finished 'start_server' after 9.01 s

I thought that deploying in 'staging' mode would set the NODE_ENV to 'staging'... not sure

**hello.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World! Now you can call Express at 3637');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3637;

app.listen(port);
console.log('Now on ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ' server');
console.log('Express app listening on localhost:'+ port);
```

The console log states :

```
0|hello    | Now on development server
0|hello    | Express app listening on localhost:3637
```

**shipitfile.js**

```
...
// this task starts the application with PM2
shipit.blTask('start_server', function () {
    var cwd = shipit.releasePath;
    return shipit.remote( "cd " + cwd + " && npm start");
});

shipit.on('deployed', function () {
    console.log("Deployed !");
    shipit.start('start_server');
});
...
```

**package.json**

```
...
"main": "hello.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "pm2 startOrReload ecosystem.json",
...
```

ecosystem.json

```
{
  "apps" : [
    {
      "name": "hello",
      "cwd": "/opt/hello/current",
      "script": "hello.js",
      "args": "",
      "watch": true,
      "node_args": "",
      "merge_logs": true,
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "env_production": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      },
      "env_staging": {
        "NODE_ENV": "staging"
      }
    }]
}
```

what's wrong with my ecosystem.js file ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PM2, to use the production environment variables (set in env_production), you need to specify the --env  option.

[Here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#switching-environments) you can find more information about it.

To solve your issue just add the --env production to your start attribute in the package.json:

```
"start": "pm2 startOrReload ecosystem.json --env production",
```

Comment: Thanks ! in this case I need to set 2 scripts , start-staging and start-production in my package.json file...